# Do you have to explicitly call setNeedsDisplay after calling setFrame on a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview

Do you have to explicitly call `setNeedsDisplay` after calling `setFrame` on `UIView` as shown in the following cases?

```
view1.frame = frame;
[view1 setNeedsDisplay];

[view2 setFrame:frame];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

You call `setNeedsDisplay` when you need method `drawRect` to be called, and according to `UIView Class Reference`.-

> Changing the frame rectangle automatically redisplays the receiver
>   without invoking the drawRect: method. If you want the drawRect:
>   method invoked when the frame rectangle changes, set the contentMode
>   property to UIViewContentModeRedraw.

Comment: But `setNeedsDisplay` call after every `setFrame` and `.frame =` is equal to `contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw`?

Comment: Not exactly: `UIViewContentModeRedraw
Redisplays the view when the bounds change by invoking the setNeedsDisplay method.` bounds property is not equivalent to frame.

Comment: Thanks, is `setFrame` absolutely equivalent to `.frame`?

Comment: Yes, it is. In general terms, `dot + property` is equivalent to the property setter

Comment: nice, I was calling set needs display for all subviews which uses custom draw method and when orientation changes in autolayout

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes and No both, depends on the situation,

**Case 1**. If you are drawing something by overriding the drawRect method in a
    custom view, ie a subclass of UIView then you will need to call
    setNeedsDisplay, otherwise that drawing or that pattern will get
    stretched according the new frame and will look bad.**If you want to redraw it, call   setNeedsDisplay.**

**Case 2**.  If at all you are
    drawing something which will look fine, even if it is stretched,
    which I think is a rare possibility,

Or  you don't override drawRect at all, **then you don't need to call
    setNeedsDisplay.**

Comment: Not entirely correct, the 'stretching' will only happen based on the contentMode setting (which by default is set to scale in most cases). However a 'UIViewcontentModeRedraw' would mean you wouldn't need to call setNeedsDisplay if the actual bounds of the view changed as it would call setNeedsDisplay on your behalf.